# Add image and hyperlink in auto response email (after form submission)

Tags: image, forms, email, hyperlink, response

I am new to php and building my first project.

I am creating a auto response email which will be sent to user after form submission.

The auto response email need to have content as follows,

> Logo image
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Here you can view our case study.(need to link pdf file to view**)

I manage to get text. but not able to add image and hyperlink.
tried using variable to store image url but code is visible instead of an image.
i request if someone Please guide me.to solve this.

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['email'];
$from = "info@company.com"; 
$headers = "From: company";
$subject = "Thank you for contacting us.";
//$img='<img src="http://www.http://company.com/images/logo.jpg"/>';
$linkedin='Linkedin';
$twitter='Twitter';
$message=
"Dear ".$firstname." Thank you for contacting us.
Here you can view our case study.
www.company.com/data/casestudy.pdf
www.company.com | info@company.com | Linkedin | Twitter 
";
$mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: What about 
``$img='<img src="http://www.http://company.com/images/logo.jpg"/>';
$message=
"Dear ".$firstname." Thank you for contacting us.
Here you can view our case study.
www.company.com/data/casestudy.pdf . " . $img . "
www.company.com | info@company.com | Linkedin | Twitter 
";``

Comment: thanks  let me try it

Comment: oopps  it gives a same error                                                                      <img src="http://www.http://company.com/images/logo.jpg"/>Dear frank Thank you for contacting us.

 Here you can view our case study. www.company.com/data/casestudy.pdf www.company.com | info@company.com | Linkedin | Twitter

Comment: also how do i add hyperlink to view word????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, In $header add content type to HTML

```
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

This will set mail Content type to HTML, Now you can add all Tags and link of HTML without using variables, So full code will be like this

```
    <?php
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $from = "info@company.com"; 
        $headers = "From: company";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $subject = "Thank you for contacting us.";
        $message="<img src='http://company.com/images/logo.jpg'/>
       <br/>Dear ".$firstname." Thank you for contacting us.
       Here you can view our case study.
       <a href='www.example.com'>File Name </a>
       www.company.com | info@company.com |<a href='www.linkedin.com'>Linkedin</a> |<a href='twitter.com'> Twitter</a> 
            ";
            $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
```

And don't get confused in single-quotes and double-quotes used here also i assume your $firstname has some value.

Comment: Thank you so much . hyper link works. image icon is there only the image is not visible. i guess something is wrong with the path . that i will figure out. thank you once again

Comment: one more help is appreciated if possible. i want send file as an attachment uploaded by user in the form. but without using server,only email. no need backup at the server. except file upload field rest of the form working fine